# Why modern web browsers don't support XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-2.0

We are thinking to use Altova StyleVision. We can create a good report template with it. Altova's default browser shows our work very well. However, generated XSLT files are not supported by the modern web browser.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's very hard to answer "why" questions, especially questions about how browser vendors choose to invest their money. However open their products may be, the process by which they make decisions has most of us completely bewildered.

Comment: is it very difficult to support XSLT 2.0? I heard W3 recommend even XSLT 3.0 .

Comment: Implementing XSLT 2.0 is probably a 10 person-year project, depending of course on the competence of the implementor.

Comment: The cost may be big for us but it shouldn't be problem for Microsoft  and Google.thanks for response :)

Comment: You would think so. But even in MS and Google, someone who wants to start a project that costs money has to put forward a business justification, and in a world where the people who want the software don't actually want to pay for it, I've no idea how that is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon CE (http://saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) brings XSLT 2.0 to modern browsers with Javascript enabled, so perhaps that is an option for you. Otherwise you will need to make sure you run the XSLT on the server and provide the transformation result to the browser.

Comment: Martin's answer is as good as it gets, unfortunately, as the risk of losing browser support for XSLT altogether is probably greater than the likelihood of ever seeing XSLT 2.0 natively supported.

Answer (score 4):

"Why" questions are always complicated as there's generally not a single answer.  But I think part of the answer is that there isn't a good implementation of XSLT 2.0 written in C or C++, in the way that [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) (the backend of xsltproc) and [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) exist for XSLT 1.0.  It's not my intention to start a language war, but for better or worse, most browsers are written in C or C++.